# Evaluation of GNU make conditionals

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The following snippet

```
ifeq (1,1)
    a = 1
    $(info true)
endif
ifeq (1,0)
    a = 0
    $(info false)
endif

$(info $(a))
```

prints

```
true
1
```

And I get it. If I were to put the same thing inside a `define` and then evaluate

```
define foo
ifeq (1,1)
    a = 1
    $(info true)
endif
ifeq (1,0)
    a = 0
    $(info false)
endif
endef

$(eval $(call foo))
$(info $(a))
```

It prints

```
true
false
1
```

The `ifeq (1,0)` doesn't evaluates to true (as the value of `$(a)` is 1 finally). But then why did it print `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because before make parses the results of the evaluation, it first expands the string to be evaluated.

The `info` function is being expanded when the argument to `eval` is being expanded, *before* make parses the code.  You need to defer the `info` until `eval` examines it by escaping the `$`:

```
define foo
ifeq (1,1)
    a = 1
    $$(info true)
endif
ifeq (1,0)
    a = 0
    $$(info false)
endif
endef
```

Comment: Ah. The dereferencing syntax resulted in execution of a built-in function. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, expansion results in expanding ALL variables and functions, built-in or not.  And, expansion is recursive.  There are only a few ways to avoid it (escape the `$` or use the `$(value ...)` function).